# What are the parts of sentence in example?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

### Navigation available in Bootstrap share general markup and styles, from the base .nav class to the active and disabled states.

My guess:

- navigation - noun;
- available - adjective;
- Bootstrap - noun;
- share - verb/noun?;
- general - adjective/noun?;
- markup - noun;
- styles - noun.

Comment: Are you sure that that sentence is complete?

Comment: No. Here complete sentence: Navigation available in Bootstrap share general markup and styles, from the base `.nav` class to the active and disabled states.

Comment: _Share_ is a verb and _general_ is an adjective. Your other guesses are correct.

Comment: Ok. Why **share** didn't end with **s**?

Comment: I have explained why in my answer.

Comment: Max, next time you should include the whole sentence, ask about *share* in the question, and maybe even explain why you’re asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Share* is a verb and *general* is an adjective. Your other guesses are correct.

*Share* does not end with *s* because *navigation* is acting as a collective noun in this instance. I am not too familiar with bootstrap but it's safe to assume that *navigation* here refers to a group of style tags. That's why *share* takes the plural form.

Comment: It really should say something like "Navigation actions..." so that it is clearly plural. As written it may be technically correct if you understand the context, but it sounds wrong.

Comment: @user3169 Yes, I agree that it sounds wrong. It took some googling for me to understand why _navigation_ was acting as a collective noun in this instance.

Comment: You might want to add a reference link regarding that.

Comment: @user3169 I mean, it had nothing to do with grammar. I just looked at some code that used the .nav bootstrap component.